# Custom WP deactivate an email activation link sent to user's email.

Tags: customization, links, email, activation

As the title stated, instead of using the WP default recovery password page, I created a custom reset password recovery page template.

Everything is working except I'm not sure how deactivate the the activate email link sent to the user. Is there a way to deactivate the link sent to them?

I've searched online and I'm stuck on how this process works in WordPress. I've also looked at the WP DB description and not able to find a field related to this issue. Has anyone encounter the same problem or have an idea of how it works?

Any help would be great!

Comment: You want to prevent the email? Or edit the link out of the email? Or cause the activation link to no longer work when a user tries to log in?

Comment: Basically set an expiration time to the reset activation link email sent to the user after they fill out the reset form. This would prevent the link to work after x hours/days. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: [I am pretty sure those links already expire.](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-login.php#L501)

Comment: I'll test it out a bit more and I'll post back here.

Comment: Okay, I test it out more and it seems like you are right. Thank you for your assistance.